# Saving forms in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm completely new to MVC having made the decision to try make the switch from aspx WebForms.
I have created a view using the MVC view creator wizard and selected a strongly typed class and an edit Scaffold template.

I got the following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Company</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>        

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

In the Controller I have the following to get the model details

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var uow = new BlogUow();
        var company = uow.Companies.GetById(id);
        return View(company);
    }
```

This works fine but the problem is, I'm stumped on how I actually save the newly entered details.
I relied too much on how the web forms handle post backs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write a post action for your edit in the controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Companies company)
    {
      var uow = new BlogUow();
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         uow.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
        return View(company);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that, I get an error saying the 2 methods are ambiguous

Comment: Did you try my method? It has different params than get method

Comment: I tried my own similar method. Method naming works different in MVC I guess. I found the problem. It was with my data annotations. Its working fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

note Companies overload

```
  [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(Companies company)
            {
              var uow = new BlogUow();
              if (ModelState.IsValid)
              {
                 Edit here
               }
                return View(company);
            }
```